# Removing a device driver module that was statically compiled

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I compiled the linux kernel with serial device driver statically i.e obj-y.

Now I'm working on a simple serial driver and I want to test it, but since the module is loaded when the kernel boots up, the IO port regions (0x3f8 and onwards) are registered to the serial module. I need to remove(unregister) it so that I can allocate it to my driver.

So, is there any way to remove the statically linked device driver ? or should I recompile the whole kernel :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should recompile the whole kernel and make this driver an `obj-m`.

Once it's loaded (either done automatically by `modprobe` or manually with `insmod`), you may remove it (using `rmmod`), modify the code, compile it again and load it again.

Of course, if there was some critical error that was not handled properly during the driver's operation, the whole kernel will be in an unstable state and you will have to reboot (until you fix what causes this).

Comment: yep, thanks for your quick reply. Already started compiling :-D

Comment: One more possible idea just in case we don't want to build kernel again is, unbind driver and then load/bind new custom driver.